# Map url parameters to objects using RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

is there a way to map the parameters in an URL to the results?

I got a rest service where the user can search something by its ID. The path is `search/:id`
The results contains the name and other properties but not the ID.

I could do something like this:

```
NSArray *array = mappingResult.array;
for (Item *item in array) {
        [item setId:itemID];
}
```

but I hope there is a nicer way...

Thanks for any hints
Xean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the path pattern you specify in your response descriptor. Then you want to use routing (`RKRoute`) and metadata during your mapping. The metadata includes a routing section which gives access to the parameters extracted from the URL path.

Some info on metadata [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html) (the docs are a little lacking).

In your mapping you want to use:

```
@metadata.routing.parameters.id
```

As the mapping source key path.

---

To make routing work you need to add the route to your object manager:

```
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:...
```

And then you need to make the request in a way that means the route is used, like `getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure:`.

Comment: This is the right way. My problem is that `@metadata.routing` dosn't exists.

Comment: Are you using `RKRoute`? You will need to show your mappings, response descriptors and route configuration to get more help...

Comment: My route is `[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Item class] pathPattern:@"search/:id" method:RKRequestMethodGET];`. ResponseDescriptor is the same like @micha-mazaheri wrote. I added the mapping from @Wain with `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:`

Comment: Ok, so you create a route instance. Are you setting it onto an object manager and how are you triggering the download (to use the route)?

Comment: Yes: `[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[Item responseDescriptors]];`. I call `[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:(...) failure:(...)];` to start the request. I was debbugging to get the keys of the metadata in `RKMappingOperation`. The mapping is working except of the `@metadata` thing. The path is a string like "search/123"

Comment: The `routing` field will only be added when the path is nil (see `RKObjectManager` line 580). So it can't work, right?

Comment: With `getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:success:failure:` it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify the `pathPattern` and `keyPath` of your ***response descriptor***::

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
  [RKResponseDescriptor
   responseDescriptorWithMapping:itemMapping
   method:RKRequestMethodAny
   pathPattern:@"search/:id"
   keyPath:@"item"
   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```